# Having an interview for another position, same company - because first position has weird Hiring Manager

Tags: interviewing

I have a second interview scheduled soon.
I already had a first interview via phone and I got a bad feeling about the Hiring Manager with whom I talked to.
The Hiring Manager sounded kinda weird and I fear of getting into a bad workplace.

Today I noticed that another position is open and is a lot closer to me (without the above Hiring Manager).
Both positions are in the same field, so technically I'm a good fit for both.

How do I tell the recruiter that I want to get the other position?

After the first phone interview I called the recruiter and said that I want to get interviewed to additional positions in the company.
The recruiter asked me If I don't want the first position and I said that I want it (I didn't want to lose a position which is perhaps good, but now I don't want to take a risk).
The recruiter said that I can't be interviewed to other positions in parallel.

Notes (due to the questions/comments below):

- Both positions are in the same company.
- The recruiter works for the company.

Comment: I'm confused. By HR, do you mean Human Resources? Maybe you instead mean Hiring Manager?

Comment: Or are these positions at two different companies?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie
HR = Hiring Manager.
Both positions are in the same company.

Comment: HR does not mean Hiring Manager. You can modify your question to use the correct term.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I edited my question regarding Hiring Manager

Comment: Sweet. And it would be good to clarify. Who does this recruiter work for? The company, or you?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie The recruiter works for the company.

Comment: Sorry for the gazillion questions, did the recruiter reach out to you? Or did you contact the company, and they are handling your application?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I did the first contact by submitting my CV to a position. Only later they said that the position to which I applied - is no longer active, but they have another position for me (which is the "first position" in my post above).

Comment: So you are worried about a "bad workplace" but are willing to be interviewed by a different hiring manager at the same company.  But that "bad workplace" would be the company itself.  I am shocked the recruiter would be gate keeping potential hires. Something is off by the situation you describe

Answer (score 7):

The recruiter has said you cannot apply to two positions in parallel. That's their rule. So, either you wait until you are offered the job you don't want (because the hiring manager sounded funny to you) and decline it, or wait until that hiring manager tells the recruiter you're not a good candidate, or you tell the recruiter you don't want that one but you do want to work for the company so please consider you for other ones. Those are your choices.

You say you don't want to lose a position that is "perhaps good". This implies you wouldn't decline the offer if you got it. You don't seem to have considered how your application to the other department might be affected by the first department not choosing you. Switching your application to a better fit might be your best approach. Or perhaps taking the "perhaps good" position and hoping for a transfer.

What isn't an option is for you to ignore their rules and work out a way to make their recruiter (who works for them) let you do something they've already told you that you cannot do.

Comment: When you say "their" rule, do you mean the recruiters, or the companies?

Comment: the recruiter works for the company; they have the same set of rules.

Comment: I've been in situations where the recruiter has their own process for doing things because they are sort of contracted out. I wouldn't be surprised if the recruiter is just trying to avoid some work by trying to get the first role across the finish line.

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks for the answer. I think there's a misunderstanding - I am willing to lose the first position just so I can have the second position which is closer to me and hopefully has a friendly Hiring Manager.

Comment: In that case, tell the recruiter so. Give up your "claim" on the first and ask to be considered for another. And do it before the first one tells the recruiter you're not a good candidate, which could hurt you for the second one

Comment: @rop Note you are giving up the first position for the OPPORTUNITY to apply for the second. There are, of course, no guarantees you will get the second role.

Comment: @KateGregory How do I tell that to the recruiter? What is my excuse? That the Hiring Manager is weird? I can't say that

Comment: You had an interview and learned more about the position, and you think you will prefer [specific position] because it has more [thing you like to do] or just is a better fit.

Comment: @KateGregory Both positions are very similar, I tried looking for differences but hardly any (except for physical location / proximity to me)

Comment: @rop physical proximity would be a perfectly valid reason to give, then you can avoid the conversation about the hiring manager completely

Comment: You don't necessarily have to explain declining the first beyond "it just didn't feel like a good fit". That does happen. But by their rules, apparently you do have to decline before you can talk to the second group, to avoid wasting the first group's time; that's not unreasonable from the company's point of view.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I tell the recruiter that I want to get the other position?
>
> After the first phone interview I called the recruiter and said that I
> want to get interviewed to additional positions in the company.
>
> The recruiter asked me If I don't want the first position and I said
> that I want it (I didn't want to lose a position which is perhaps
> good, but now I don't want to take a risk).
>
> The recruiter said that I can't be interviewed to other positions in
> parallel.

You make a decision.

If you don't want the first position, then you decline it, bet on yourself and your abilities, and take a chance that you can land the second position.

If you do want the first position in spite of the manager, then you stay silent regarding the other job, and attend the second interview.

Decide, then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the manager may just not be comfortable interviewing over the phone, and you might like them in person. Or, after meeting and talking to the other members of the department, you might decide that the Manager's oddness (whatever it is) doesn't actually seem to be a problem.

If you think you might still want the first opening, and aren't willing to let go of it, wait until you've had an on-site interview, or even suggest that you'd like one.

If you're afraid the second job will be gone by the time you make a firm decision... Well, that's how this company works. There may be others opening up in the meantime. And presumably you are continuing to apply and interview at other companies in the meantime. Which might even find a better opportunity so you decline this company entirely.

But you do have to make a decision for how you want to proceed with *this* company: continue to check out the first job in case your first reaction was mistaken, or turn it down and ask to be interviewed for others ("it just didn't feel like a good personality fit" is an entirely legitimate reason for doing so).

Every choice involves a bit of a gamble. You need to decide which one(s) you're comfortable with. We can't do that for you; we don't know the jobs, didn't have the interview, and most importantly aren't you.

If you really can't decide whether to finish the interview process for the first job ... Flip a coin?